# Targeting $index from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

How would I go about targeting this model in the controller?

```
formData[$index].ID
```

This is not working -

```
$scope.getJob = function() {
        Employee.get({id: "" + $scope.formData[$index].ID}, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would actually inject the object or index from your template. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in formData">
    <button ng-click="getJob($index)">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

and then in your code:

```
$scope.getJob = function(idx) {
    Employee.get({id: "" + $scope.formData[idx].ID}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Alternatively, instead of injecting the index, you could inject the entire object:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in formData">
    <button ng-click="getJob(o)">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

and then in your code:

```
$scope.getJob = function(o) {
    Employee.get({id: o.ID}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance @Dave!